# Are there other ways to update a document with Express and Mongoose without having to delete the _id property?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When I update a document with Express and Mongoose is the best practice to just delete the _id value and then save the document? Here is an example of the code I'm using.

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {
    var data = _.extend(app.locals.crewListing, req.body);
    data = data.toObject();
    delete data._id;
    app.locals.crewListing.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json({
            message: null,
            data: result
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the `_id` property from `data`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You definitely need to make sure that `_id` property isn't changed while updating. The best way is,

```
if(data._id) {
    delete data._id;
}
```

But I would prefer updating each field of the object individually instead of using `.extend()` function since you know what fields you are updating.